# Company name edited out

Tags: discussion

In [this](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/82234/what-does-this-invitation-mean) question the company name was edited out.

Should this site be editing out company names?  Assuming they are not bashing the company.

Given the size of the company it is very likely people on this site have interviewed with the company.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it OK to name and shame?](http://meta.workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/4109/is-it-ok-to-name-and-shame)

Comment: @DoritoStyle Where is the shame?

Comment: The relevant bit is the name, not the shame.

Comment: @DoritoStyle I irrelevant part is I specifically state are not bashing the company.

Comment: That's irrelevant. The attention doesn't need to be negative to attract legal issues or to be off-topic to this site. At the end of the day, The Workplace is simply not a employer review site and such specific details have been deemed off-topic by the community over a relatively large period of time.

Answer (score 3):

> Should this site be editing out company names?

(shrug) It happens. I don't care much either way.

For this question, there's no added value in having the company name in the question body.

But as you indicated, unless the questioner is bashing or making unfounded statements about the company, I don't see any reason to remove the name.

In general, I think it's silly for folks to name the company they have an issue with. There's simply no need for it, and no benefit to anyone knowing that you have had to wait 2 weeks to hear from HR at "MegaCorp", rather than "the company".

If you want to name names, go to GlassDoor. That's their whole point for being, but not ours.

Comment: I see a lot of value if someone had been to an Amazon interview.  Given the size of the company I suspect this site has a lot of people that have been on an Amazon interview.

Comment: @Paparazzi - the questions isn't (and really cannot) be Amazon-specific. If it were about Best Buy or Target or any other company with a huge on-line presence, the advice would be exactly the same.

Comment: You say you don't care much either way, but in your answer [here](http://meta.workplace.stackexchange.com/a/4111/62190) you say that you're not ok with it at all and that you flag posts you see which contain company names. Is this a little contradictory, or am I missing something? Is the difference that you're ok with companies being named if there are only positive comments about them, but object if people are posting negative things about specific companies?

Comment: @3N1GM4 - (shrug) I'm an enigma, wrapped in a puzzle, wrapped in a workplace. But it's the "shaming" part that I'm not okay with at all. That should be banned, IMHO. Other than that I don't care.

Comment: Haha, fair enough. :)

Answer (score -1):

Publishing the names of companies will lead to no good.

When mentioned in a positive light, it will look like we are shilling.  When mentioned in a negative light, it will look like we are bashing.  Either way leads to liability.

If a company is mentioned in a good light, and someone goes there and has a bad experience, SE could be exposed to liability from the person who had a bad experience.

If it's mentioned in a bad light, the company could retaliate, again, exposing SE to liability.

Reputation monitoring is big business right now, and companies who have their names mentioned will be visiting this site.  It's just easier for all concerned to edit them out.

Comment: SE is not liable for advice or opinions express on the site

Comment: @Paparazzi until it is.  There are many ways to legally harass a company without actually going to court.  A company would start with a letter and/or an email demanding that any reference be taken down, and that any future mentions of them would be met with legal action, and could cause SE all sorts of mischief.  Better to avoid unwanted attention.